# Executing a method from a different class file

Tags: java

I am unable to run the following program using another class. Can anyone show me how to do it? I used another class file named msgTester and ran methodA()

```
class msg{
  public int content;
}

public class Quiz8A{

  public int sum;
  public int y;

  public void methodA() {
    int x=0, y =0, i=0;
      msg mg = new msg();
      mg.content = 1;
      while (i<3) {
        y = y + mg.content;
        methodB(mg);
        x = y + mg.content;
        sum += x + y;
        System.out.println(x + " " + y+ " " + sum);
        i++;
      }
    }

    private void methodB(msg mg2){
      int x = 0;
      y = y + mg2.content;
      x = x + 3 + y;
      sum = x + y;
      mg2.content = x;
      System.out.println(x + " " + y+ " " + sum);
    }
  }
```

This is the test class:

```
 public class msgTester { 

   public static void main(String[] args) { 

     Scanner abc = new Scanner(System.in); 
     msg A = new msg(); 
     A.methodA(); 

  } 
}
```

Comment: Show us the code of msgTester and how you execute your test.

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;
public class msgTester{
  public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner abc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    msg A = new msg();
    A.methodA();
  }
}

Comment: methodA() is present in Quiz8A class. Create a u=instance for Quiz8A and access it.  `Quiz8A A = new Quiz8A();A.methodA();`. Please follow the coding standards

Comment: Tried that as well but cannot compile

import java.util.Scanner;
public class msgTester{
  public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner abc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    Quiz8A A = new Quiz8A();
    A.methodA();
  }

Answer (score 1):

Few areas you should improve in your code.

1. Use the naming standards. Class name should starts with Caps (Class Msg)
2. Format your code, so that it will be easy to read
3. In  MsgTester Class, Scanner instance is unused.

To Answer your question.  You are try to access a method in Quiz8A  class. But you create a instance for Msg. so compiler complaints there is no such method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class msgTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner abc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Quiz8A obj = new Quiz8A();
        obj.methodA();
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah I have done sth similar to this but still no luck compiling the code

import java.util.Scanner;
public class msgTester{
  public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner abc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    Quiz8A A = new Quiz8A();
    A.methodA();
  }
}

Comment: What is the compilation error? It should work. `methodA()` is present in `Quiz8A` class right

Comment: Yes it should work. This is the error

1 error found:
File: C:\Users\mh pc\Desktop\msg.java  [line: 4]
Error: class Quiz8A is public, should be declared in a file named Quiz8A.java

Comment: Move the Quiz8A class to separate file and name as "Quiz8A.java". Read the compiler error and act accordingly.

Comment: Yes finally it has worked but I still do not understand one thing. What is the purpose of class msg ? If we cannot use it to name the java file

Comment: @ShahriarHossain  It was posted by you :) Actually speaking you can move that variable `content` in Quiz8A class and remove the Class msg. There is no need of that variable in Class msg. Before writing the code, think and understand the logic/usecase. Accept any one of the answer, if it resolved your problem

Answer (score 0):

After some reformatting of your code it was clear that you need to make a new instance of `Quiz8A` instead of msg. So your tester should look like:

```
public class msgTester { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner abc = new Scanner(System.in); 
    Quiz8A quiz8A = new Quiz8A (); 
    quiz8A.methodA(); 
  }
}
```

Just some important advide for you as a coding beginner, before you start understanding how to programm, start structuring your work:

- Format your code! This is very important for reading it.
- Use descriptives names for variables! You will get much confused by remebering which variable contains/means.
- Class names start always uppercase! Instance names are always lowercase

Comment: Still no luck

import java.util.Scanner;
public class msgTester{
  public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner abc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    Quiz8A A = new Quiz8A();
    A.methodA();
  }
}

Comment: @ShahriarHossain And what do you expect your message tester to do?